# How to detect when the current animation is finished in code in Unity's Animator?

Tags: unity, c#, animation

I have a model with an animation controller. I set the states and parameters for transitions between them. Now I need to make the model play its animations in the order I want.

I can use:

```
GetComponent.<Animator>().SetBool("someparameter",true);
```

to uncheck currently checked parameter and check another parameter after current animation finished.

Please help me to find a way to make a condition "when the current animation finished".

The examples I'm finding are related to animation component (not animator), or they are too complicated for me, while I need a simple way I can understand and use quickly.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [**State Machine Behaviours**](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/5-pre-order-beta/state-machine-behaviours)

> State machine behaviours are scripts that can be attached to animator states or sub-state machines in an Animator Controller. [...] To add a state machine behaviour to a state or sub-state machine, click the Add Behaviour button in the inspector.

Then, on the newly created state machine behaviour file, implement the [`OnStateExit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StateMachineBehaviour.OnStateExit.html) callback and set the value of your parameter

```
override public void OnStateExit (Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
{
    animator.SetBool("someparameter",false);
}
```